# I want add minutes from my seek bar

Tags: android, android-seekbar

This is my seek bar code..Here it shows hour only.i need to add minute..In seek bar itself it shows AM and PM ..it doesn't shows minutes like 10 min,20 min ...it appears in database like 11 am,4 pm..i need add minute also...is it possible in seek bar...please help me to find out the code...

```
  seekBar_startTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                double progress;
                String am_pm;
                if (progressValue > 12)
                {
                    progress = progressValue - 12;
                    am_pm = "PM";
                }
                else
                {
                    progress = progressValue;
                    am_pm = "AM";
                }

                start_Time = String.valueOf(progress+am_pm);
                textView_startTime.setText("Event Start Time :" + start_Time);
            }
        });

        seekBar_endTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue,boolean fromUser) {
                double progress;
                String am_pm;
                if (progressValue > 12)
                {
                    progress = progressValue - 12;
                    am_pm = "PM";
                }
                else
                {
                    progress = progressValue;
                    am_pm = "AM";
                }

                end_Time = String.valueOf(progress+am_pm);
                textView_endTime.setText("Event Start Time :" + end_Time);
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I added much more steps to your seekbar, so you can display every hours:minutes configuration. this  might be too many steps. If this is the case, change it to 5 minute steps. If you want to change this, go to line 4 in my code and set Progress to the desired amount of minutes, each step should have.

```
Seekbar seekbar_startTime = (Seekbar) findViewById(your seekbar id);
seekbar_startTime.setProgress(0);
seekbar_startTime.setMax(1440); //minutes in 24 hours
seekbar_startTime.setProgress(1);//set Stepsize = 1
seekBar_startTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {  
            int minutes;
            int hours;
            minutes = progressValue % 60;
            int hours = progressValue/60;
            String am_pm;
            if (hours> 12)
            {
                hours= hours- 12;
                am_pm = "PM";
            }
            else
            {
                am_pm = "AM";
            }

            String start_Time = ""+hours+":"+minutes+am_pm;
            textView_startTime.setText("Event Start Time :" + start_Time);
        }
    });



    seekBar_endTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue,boolean fromUser) {
            int minutes;
            int hours;
            minutes = progressValue % 60;
            int hours = progressValue/60;
            String am_pm;
            if (hours> 12)
            {
                hours= hours- 12;
                am_pm = "PM";
            }
            else
            {
                am_pm = "AM";
            }

            String end_Time = ""+hours+":"+minutes+am_pm;
            textView_endTime.setText("Event Start Time :" + end_Time);
        }


    });
```

If there are any copy paste errors from your code im sorry :) threw this together really quick.

Comment: seekbar_startTime.setMax(1660);  is wrong ....24*60=1440...so i need to put 1440...correct

Comment: @Sathya yea i derped with the numbers. gonna change that :D maybe mark ask answer? :)